# Python overwriting and resizing list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to create a list in python of a fixed size, let's so 3 to begin with. I have a method that writes data to this list every time the method is called, I want to add this to the list until the list is full, once the list is full it should start overwriting the data in the list in ascending order (e.g. starting with element 0). I also want to add a function which will increase the length of the array, i.e. if the method is called the array will increase from size 3 to size 4. How do I go about doing either of these?

Comment: Have you searched or tried anything already? are you familiar with `collections.deque()`?

Comment: I was trying to just show the final 3 elements in the list i.e. list[-3:] however this does not suit the problem at hand.

Comment: This is actually a very nice exercise for you. So, try doing it yourself first. Just take a look at what properties and methods lists have and you are set.

Comment: what do you mean by the list is full? It will never be full, till you ran out of memory

Comment: I mean as in if I set it as size 3 and there are 3 elements within the list, I don't want to list to get bigger as more elements are being appended, instead I'd like to overwrite the elements that are already in the list

Comment: @kmario23 A list of a fixed size can very well be full.

Comment: @Alex.S What is a list of a fixed size?

Comment: @Kasramvd List on `n` elements when `n` is constant. Some programming languages do have lists of fixed size. For example, C.

Comment: Look up "circular queue". Setting one up and using it is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple solution should do:

```
def add(l, item, max_len):
    l.insert(0, item)
    return l[:max_len]

l = ["banana", "peanut", "bicycle", "window"]
l = add(l, "monkey", 3)

print(newlist)
```

prints:

```
> ['monkey', 'banana', 'peanut']
```

The the list to edit (`l`), the item to add and the max size (`max_len`) of the list are arguments.

The item will then be added at index 0, while the list is limited to max_len.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. There are tons of prebuilt modules that have similar functionality but I thought it would be best if you could visualize the process!

```
class SizedList(list):
    def __init__(self, size):
        list().__init__(self)
        self.__size = size
        self.__wrap_location = 0
        self.len = len(self)

    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.len = len(self)
        if self.len >= self.__size:
            if self.__wrap_location == self.__size-1:
                self.__wrap_location = 0
            self.__wrap_location += 1
            self.pop(self.__wrap_location)
            return self.insert(self.__wrap_location-1, *args)
        return list.append(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def increase_size(self, amount=1):
        self.__size += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I went about it in the end. I set a variable called length_list which was originally set at 3.

```
def add_to_list():

   if len(list) < length_list:
      append
   else:
      del list[0]
   self.add_to_list()

def increase_length():
    length_list += 1
```